# monitor with operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to write a wrapper class with all operators overloaded such that I can detect when we write/read or modify its contents. For instance:

```
probe<int> x;
x = 5;     // write
if(x) {    // read
   x += 7; // modify
}
```

Anyone already did that? If not which operators must I overload to be sure I dont miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, I think. operator?: isn't overloadable. Also, if `T::T(int)` is defined, `T foo = 4` is legal but `T foo = probe<int>(4)` isn't. There's at most one user-defined conversion.

Furthermore, because probe is not a POD, the behavior of your program can change.

Comment: T foo = probe<int>(4) is legal.

Comment: can you provide an example of the problem you mentionned with "?:"

Comment: @Mykoala: T foo = T(probe<int>(4)); would be legal. probe->int->T is two conversions.

A prob with ?: exists when you use probe<int> as second arg and probe<float> as the third. No common type. With operator+(probe<int>, probe<float>) you can fix it with lot of overloads.

Comment: Can't we fix it with a base class ?

Comment: No - int cannot be used as a base class.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as a common idea.
There are plenty of operators like &= |= [] which maybe are not principal in your case.

```
template < typename T >
struct monitor
{
    monitor( const T& data ):
        data_( data )
    {
        id_ = get_next_monitor_id(); 
    }

    monitor( const monitor& m )
    {
       id_ = get_next_monitor_id();

       m.notify_read();
       notify_write();

       data_ = m.data_;
    }

    operator T()
    {
        notify_read();
        return data_;    
    }

    monitor& operator = ( const monitor& m )
    {
        m.notify_read();
        notify_write();

        data_ = m.data_;
        return *this;
    }

    monitor& operator += ( const monitor& m )
    {
        m.notify_read();
        notify_write();

        data_ += m.data_;
        return *this;
    }
/*
    operator *=
    operator /=
    operator ++ ();
    operator ++ (int);
    operator -- ();
    operator -- (int);
*/
private:
    int id_;
    T data_;

    void notify_read()
    {
        std::cout << "object " << id_ << " was read" << std::endl;
    }

    void notify_write()
    {
        std::cout << "object " << id_ << " was written" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: ++ and -- postfix and prefix (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14)

Comment: Still missing a ton? &=, |= are commonly used.

Also, binary operators like + might not be needed. If they are, what overloads do you provide exactly, and how do you make it properly symmetric?

Comment: a simple example with std::cout << "read/write/modify" would be welcome

Comment: Yeah plenty of operators. Don't meet &= for ages in c++ code though.

Comment: It's not very common, but I did use it in my last project.

Comment: @Helltone: you can put cout << "attempt to modify" to all operators, put "attempt to read" to copy constructor and operator T().

Comment: Note that you are limiting the usage. You cannot pass the wrapper as a non-const reference to a function taking the wrapped type. The cast operator will provide you with a temporary, but not with a reference.

Comment: @dribeas: If a function expect an wrapped type and we pass montior there, simply will be called operator T() and read notification will take place. What is the problem, can you describe in other words?